# Angular, conditional class swapping

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I'm trying to class swap and change a click function based on the data coming in:

Here's what I'm working with (this is inside an ng-repeat):

```
<div class="saPromptTypeHeadSub" ng-class="{'saSubPromptOpen': !showNow, 'saSubPromptClosed': showNow, 'saSubPromptClosed': fade.showOptions != 1}" ng-click="showNow = ! showNow" >
```

The showNow toggles something below it with an ng-show="!showNow" to hide/show itself based on the click. I'm trying to combine the showOptions == 1 && shownow logic into 1 argument for the ng class but I am having some issues.

I basically want it to offset the showNow and class by 1 so it starts as showNow and with the sub prompt closed class (the reverse of normal) when the fade.showOptions != 1. I'm not sure how an argument like that would work in angular. Any help would be much appreciated, as this one as stumped me for a while. Thanks!

Comment: You can't use `saSubPromptClosed` twice

Comment: Yes, that was just an attempt to see what I could do inside angulars ng-class.

Comment: I'm not sure how to apply that logic to angulars methods in this case. Care to elaborate?

Comment: I'm sorry but the question isn't clear to me 
Do you want to apply saSubPromptClosed class when both logics return true or even if anyone of them is true, you want the class to be applied?

Comment: Apologies for the confusion. When it comes in as 1 I want it to work as normal. When the showOptions != 1 I want it to sort of reverse, so it would start out with the opposite class and the click would start on the opposite click, so if when I land normally I have the class of saSubPromptOpen and !showNow, when  showOptions != 1, the item would start with saSubPromptClosed and showNow (keep in mind this is in a repeat). Hopefully that clears things up, thanks! @AhsanAyaz

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As I understood your question, this seems to be the trick

```
<div class="saPromptTypeHeadSub" ng-class="{'saSubPromptOpen': !showNow || fade.showOptions == 1, 'saSubPromptClosed': showNow || fade.showOptions != 1}" ng-click="showNow = ! showNow" >
```

when showNow will be false OR fade.showOptions==1 then saSubPromptOpen will be the class applied
and when when showNow will be true OR fade.showOptions!=1 then saSubPromptClosed will be the class applied

But you are using an ng-repeat, so the showNow model, fade.showOptions these are all same for all list items (and are not related to a specific li) .

I don't know what you're trying to achieve with the current logic but I guess i've answered the question :)

Comment: This is perfect, I'm also trying to get the section below it to hide when they are reversed, right now it's controller by this ng-show="!showNow". My attempt based off your answer was this :<div class="saPromptTypeBodySub" ng-show="!showNow && fade.showOptions == 1 || showNow || fade.showOptions != 1" >. This did not seem to work. Any insight? Thanks again!

Comment: <div class="saPromptTypeBodySub" ng-show="showNow || fade.showOptions == 1">

this would work. 
It'll be shown when any of the above condition is true, else it'll hide